# Is there a way to avoid the XmlSerializer to not initialize a null property when deserializing?

Tags: .net, xmlserializer

I have this class:

```
public class MySerializableClass
{
    public List<MyObject> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

If MyList is null when MySerializableClass is serialized, I need to have it null when it's deserialised too, but the XmlSerializer always initializes it when it deserialises my class.

Is there a way to avoid it initializing null properties?

MyList is not even recorded in the serialized file when it's null. When I load it with null values, and save it again, MyList is not null anymore, it's serialized as a List<> with 0 items, but not null.

Thanks.

More info:

An IsDeserializing property is not viable due to some code restrictions in the structure of the class

Comment: Wow, System.Xml never seizes to surprise me.  Having a public setter for a collection class member is *very* unusual, review your design to verify that's what you really want.  It works okay without a setter.

Comment: It's not what I really want. It's what the serializer wants. If I make either the get or set private, the deserializer will fail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This looks like a bug...

Even if you try to mark the property as nullable, it doesn't seem to work.

```
[XmlArray(IsNullable = true)]
public List<MyObject> MyList { get; set; }
```

It serializes the MyList property as follows :

```
<MyList xsi:nil="true" />
```

So the XML clearly indicates that the list is null, but after deserialization, it is still initialized to an empty list...

If you replace `List<MyObject>` with `MyObject[]`, it works fine (even without `IsNullable = true`), but it's probably not what you want...

You should probably report this on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Once you've reported the bug, edit your question to include the URL of the bug report. That will allow others to vote for the bug.

Comment: Please vote and add some comments here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/687096/xmlserializer-initializes-a-list-when-it-should-not

Comment: It is still a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/89420

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Auto-Implemented Properties if you need a null there. 
use e.g.

```
public class MySerializableClass 
{ 
    List<MyObject> myList 
    public List<MyObject> MyList { get {return myList;} set {myList = value;} } 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem, try it.

Comment: Yeah, I actually have it like this, I simplified it for the example, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

If you add a property with the name *PropertyName*Specified as a boolean the XmlSerializer will render the tag for the list only when it is true.

Example:

```
public class MySerializableClass
{
    public List<MyObject> MyList { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool MyListSpecified { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem but adding the XmlArrayAttribute to the property with nothing set made it work for me

```
public class MySerializableClass
{
    [XmlArray]
    public List<MyObject> MyList { get; set; }
}
```