# How do I set a list to null in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm reading an .xml file and, depending on the element, there might or might not be a dependencies tag.

```
[XmlArray("dependencies"), XmlArrayItem("dependency")]
public List<string> Dependencies { get; set; }
```

When there is no < dependencies >, I want the list to be set to null, which I tried to do with

```
List<string> Dependencies = null;
```

However, when I deserialize my xml, dependencies is shown as Count=0. I want it show up as set to null, so when I serialize it back, I don't get the empty < dependencies /> tag as useless clutter in my xml file. This worked splendidly with a string, which I simply set to = null, but with lists, this somehow doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefix a method with ShouldSerialize and set the return type to bool, then you could override whether or not the xmlserializer would serialze the current property. In this case it would not serialize the Dependencies if the count is zero.

```
    [XmlArray("dependencies"), XmlArrayItem("dependency")]
    public List<string> Dependencies { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeDependencies()
    {
        if (Dependencies != null && Dependencies.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the IsNullable property on the XmlArray attribute

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("dependencies", IsNullable=true)]
```

The side effect is that you will get `xsi:nill=true` attribute on your `dependencies` element but it is a small price if your schema supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the IsNullable attribute to true:

```
[XmlArray("dependencies"), XmlArrayItem("dependency"), IsNullable = true]
public List<string> Dependencies { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188619/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-the-xmlserializer-to-not-initialize-a-null-property-when). A suggestion here is to use [XmlArray] without parameters. IsNullable will not get you the clean XML you want.